# How to get ObservableCollection item by ListView SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I created a ListView and set a ObservableCollection to ItemsSource.

Then, I can use a int to binding SelectedIndex, it's work well.

But I don't know how to get item's detail when I selected.

I want to get ObservableCollection, then binding it to show on a TextBlock.

My TextBlock and ListView are difference UserControl. ViewModel in MainWindow.

So I want to know how to get ObservableCollection item by ListView SelectedIndex?

Or others method to resolve it?

Thx.

ViewModel in MainWinodw:

```
public class TestVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _index;
    public int Index
    {
        get
        {
            return _index;
        }
        set
        {
            _index = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Index");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<User> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<User> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        private set
        {
            _items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<User> _collection;
    public ObservableCollection<User> Collection
    {
        get
        {
            return _collection;
        }
        private set
        {
            _collection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Collection");
        }
    }

    ListCollectionView _groupView;
    public ListCollectionView GroupView
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupView;
        }
        private set
        {
            _groupView = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("GroupView");
        }
    }

    public TestVM()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe1", Age = 10, group = "Group 1" });
        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe2", Age = 20, group = "Group 1" });

        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 30, group = "Group 2" });
        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe1", Age = 40, group = "Group 2" });
        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe2", Age = 50, group = "Group 2" });

        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe3", Age = 60, group = "Group 3" });
        Collection.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe4", Age = 70, group = "Group 3" });

        GroupView = new ListCollectionView(Collection);
        GroupView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("group"));
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public int Age { set; get; }

    public string group { get; set; }
}
```

ListView in UserControl1:

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupView}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Index}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <local:GridViewColumnExt Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <local:GridViewColumnExt x:Name="colAge" Header="Age" Width="50">
                    <local:GridViewColumnExt.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="{Binding Age}"></Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:GridViewColumnExt.CellTemplate>
                </local:GridViewColumnExt>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
```

TextBlock in UserControl2 (Just want to show item detail) :

```
<WrapPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="SelectdIndex: "/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" />
</WrapPanel>
```

MainWindow.xmal

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:TestVM/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:StepList Grid.Column="0"></local:StepList>
        <local:ItemDetail Grid.Column="1"></local:ItemDetail>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the details of the selected item in ListView to show up in the Textbox you have to set the binding in the Textbox.

e.g.

```
Text="{Binding SelectedItem.EnterThePropertyToShowhere, ElementName=EnterTheNameOfyourListViewhere, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"
```

Edit 3: Ok forgett what I said. Try:

Add to your Listview

```
SelectedItem="{Bindig SelectedUser , UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"
```

Add to your ViewModel a property SelectedUser with propertychange Notification

```
public User SelectedUser{
     get { return _selectedUser; }
     set
     {
        if (value == _selectedUser) return;
        _selectedUser= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedUser");
     }
  }
```

Add to your Textbox:

```
 Text="{Binding SelectedUser.PropertyWhichShouldShow, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"
```

Comment: In fact, my TextBlock and ListView are difference UserControl. ViewModel in MainWindow. How can I get SelectedItem.EnterThePropertyToShowhere and EnterTheNameOfyourListViewhere?

Comment: @黃柏森 Please provide code for relevant classes. My answer was as precise as it could be with the information you provided.

Comment: OK, I provide some content, I don't know what are you need. So, if you want to know something, just tell me. Thx.

Comment: @黃柏森 please add mainwindow xaml. At least where your usercontrols are loaded.

Comment: I try your Text="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=lv, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}", but it don't work. I think it isn't know "lv".

Comment: And, I want to get SelectedItem's property, no SelectedIndex. I don't know how to get it, if SelectedItem is User object.

Comment: Sorry... What's SelectedUser  type? User or ItemCollection? I don't know what's set/get this property? use "_collection" var?

Comment: Then, I declare type "User"/"ItemCollection" are not work and error. What's my miss?

Comment: @黃柏森 please upload your project somewhere i can load it. I dont get what you mean. Have you seen my latest edit? There is all you need. Tested it in an new Project and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, wait. I debug something

Comment: Maybe you are right, but I have some bug need to resolve.

Comment: Ok. Accept the answer if you feel I helped you.